# No craft_users table in Database

Tags: login

Good Afternoon.

Im trying to recover admin login information for a website I have recently taken on, however there is no craft_users table within the database.  Any help to locate the user info would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

There are so many tables that phpMyAdmin paginates them. All the tables that came after craft_tags alphabetically are on the second page, making it look like there is no craft_users table. Pagination controls are at the top:

[image: craft_users is on the second page]

Reason I know? I just made the same mistake.

Comment: You saved my day! PMA UX is horrible! Although, resetting users can **now** be done with the [craft console](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#users-set-password) easily

Answer (score 2):

A Craft website can be configured to have a different table prefix. This can be updated in the `craft/config/db.php` file:

In this example, the prefix is the default, `craft`, so the users table will be `craft_users`

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'craft',
    )
);
```

In this example, the prefix is `unexpected` so the users table will be `unexpected_users`

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => 'unexpected',
    )
);
```

In this example, the prefix is (blank) so the users table will be `users`

```
return array(
    '*' => array(
        'tablePrefix' => '',
    )
);
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the quick response.  The database is using craft_  as the prefix.  There is just no  users table there at all. ive clicked into each table in phpmyadmin and none seem to be a users one.  Is it possible to have users on the dev site, but launch the finished site without user access, either for security or so that only the dev team can alter?

Comment: The db.php file will also probably show you the name and connection info of the DB Craft is connecting to. Maybe the one you are looking for is in a different location? I don't believe Craft support s have some DB tables in other places

Comment: Db.php confirms that the database it is connecting to is the correct one im looking at.  Id just doesnt have a users table.  If I were to create one, would this work?

Comment: If there isn't a `users` table then the Craft installation is broken and won't work anyway.

Comment: H Brad.  The webste s working in general.  But ive just set up a new test site and that doesnt have anythng in the users group table that relates to the admin user